# How to trigger a js upon the exitting of the web page that created using ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I already know this..

```
$(window).unload(function executebeforeexit() {
            ...........
        });
```

and this

```
window.onbeforeunload = executebeforeexit;
        function executebeforeexit()
        {
            ................
        }
```

and they did not work for me because they executed even I navigated via the page. This the whole code written in cshtml file.==> https://docs.google.com/document/d/13Huf8uWHTCJzJCWip3sJ4H22oN6rX-rZvgp70Pmd0kk/edit
I want to know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

for help purpose it would be preferable to have your code shared in a public cloud links (ex.: http://jsbin.com/ , https://jsfiddle.net/ etc. )

usage of :

```
$(window).unload(callback)
```

is preferable to

```
window.onbeforeunload
```

If you can afford to have jquery loaded

But before going into details, please note that not all browser support having a callback on a page unloading and that it must be synchrone (async execution will never happen)

if you prefer not to use jquery for this purpose, please consider using

```
window.addEventListener('unload', callback)
```

It's more clean and allow to have multiples functions as a callback (as you can add multiple listeners) so you make sure your unload callback don't get overwrite somewhere else in your code.

If your page contain iframes or framesets, the listener might be placed on the frame itself if you require it

Comment: It is cshtml and codes like @RenderBody() will not work.